# C++ wait problem

Tags: c++, g++, ipc, fork, wait

I have a code like this

```
    if (pid > 0) {
        // Child    
    } else {
        // Parent
    }

while (wait() > 0) {}
```

And there are includes

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

But when i try to compiile it with g++ (`g++ test.cpp -o test`) a have an errors:

```
lab3.cpp: In function «int main(int, char**)»:
lab3.cpp:57:18: error: no match for «operator>» in «{0} > 0»
lab3.cpp:57:18: warning: candidates are:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_pair.h:220:67: замечание: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator>(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:304:46: замечание: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator>(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:354:47: замечание: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator>(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/bits/basic_string.h:2548:58: замечание: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator>(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/bits/basic_string.h:2560:27: замечание: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator>(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/bits/basic_string.h:2572:58: замечание: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator>(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1303:77: замечание: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator>(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `wait()` is defined in `sys/wait.h`, but I don't understand why you're getting such an error if that was the only thing missing.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is, that you are not telling us what line 57 is in your snippet.

Comment: Provide complete source code if you can (at least for that file). I think you've got something else going on we can't see there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your includes pull `/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h` indirectly, which defines a `union wait`. Since you don't have a declaration of the wait-function, C++ sees wait() as a constructor expression. This means `wait()>0` calls for an `operator>(const wait &,int)` which does not exist of course. GCC's diagnostics aren't really helpful here. Add `sys/wait.h` to fetch a valid prototype for the wait function.

Answer (score 2):

`wait()` is defined in `sys/wait.h`.

But there's probably something else going on there that we can't see with the code you posted.

Try changing that to:

```
while (::wait() > 0) ...
```

to make sure you're calling the `wait()` function from the global namespace and not some other class or construct imported from elsewhere.

Comment: Also for the OP probably use Do, might be better in what hes implementing if he indeed want to run some code atleast once.